# Jquery cannot get contents of <iframe> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Hi I am trying to select **form** tag using Jquery from the link below in chrome console:

```
http://www.dcoi-conference.org/#!registration/cpq5
```

I tried:

```
$("form")
```

This gives empty array
Here I see the **form** element is in **iframe**. Thus I also tried

```
$("iframe")[0].contents();
```

But was uanable to get any results.
Please help.

Comment: I reopened because this is not so much a question about how to read an iframe as it is an issue with cross origin security.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. I actually believed that the console could bypass the cross origin too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form in that page is in an iframe that comes from a different origin than the page.  So, the browser security model will not allow you to access the iframe DOM from the parent page.

Without moving the content out of that foreign domain or placing code into that foreign sourced iframe, there is no way to work around that security limitation from just the parent page.

Possible solutions:

1. Stop embedding an iframe from a foreign domain because there is no way to get to the content of a cross origin iframe.  Put the content into your own page directly where you can access it freely.
2. Add code to the foreign domain that will cooperate with the parent page.  Cooperating cross origin frames can communicate via `window.postMessage()`, but it requires cooperating code in both frames in both domains.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what does moving content out of that foreign domain or placing code into that foreign sourced iframe mean? @jfriend00

Comment: @wrufesh - I added possible solutions to my answer.